# Controlling muscle growth from running

Tags: running, muscle, cardio, muscle-gain, calf

**Background:**

I'm a 28 year old male, 176cm, 68kg. I used to go swimming for 60min three times a week before the pandemic. Due to the latter, public pools in my country have shut down, and I have not exercised since then. Recognising the effect on my physical and mental health, I'd like to start a new exercise routine, and running seems to be the most sensible choice.

**Question:**

However, about 10 years ago I was a very active runner (5 times a week), before I switched to swimming. I very much enjoy running, but it comes with an »annoying« side effect: My calf muscle grow very fast and very large, to the point that it looks a bit cartoonish, the rest of my body being average build.

Is there a way (or ways) to control the extend to which muscles in general and specifically the calf muscles grow from exercising them?

Comment: As someone who has to be very specific and deliberate about growing calves, let me just tell you that is frustrating to me to hear. :D But in all seriousness, I hope someone comes along with a good answer on this one.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way (or ways) to control the extend to which muscles in general and specifically the calf muscles grow from exercising them?

Yes, but nothing I think you'd want to do.  How you exercise a muscle affects how it grows (bodybuilders do higher reps & lower weights than power lifters), but not by *that* much.  Power lifters still get pretty big, and bodybuilders still get pretty strong.

Not eating much will quite literally starve the muscle of the nutrients it needs to grow.

So, short of changing your genetics, you can eat less or exercise less.

That said, you could go the other way and intentionally work the rest of your body to catch up to your calves.

Good luck whatever you decide.